# Proper adding repositories in Maven 3 pom.xml

Tags: maven-3

Every time i build something with Mavent i muss struggle with the searching a proper repo for the required Maven artifact. As now i am searching the repo for the spring-aop but can not find one. Actual pom.xml follows.

How can i approach assembling pom.xml properly?

Thanks.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-milestone</id>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.repository.maven</id>
        <name>SpringSource Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springframework.org/maven/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

The artifact `spring-aop` is [present](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-aop%7C3.1.1.RELEASE%7Cjar) in maven central repo.

Normally most of the released artifacts are present in maven central which need not be explicitly specified in `pom.xml`.  You can use the [search](http://search.maven.org/) option of the central repo for this.

In the question above, you would need to include the additional `spring` repos only if you were looking for `milestone` (alpha/beta) releases.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a repository manager [instead of added repositories to the pom](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/).